# Webpack can't load packages from node_modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-style-loader

I am starting app with [react-slingshot](https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot) start kit. I wanted to load from node_modules normalize.css and react-toolbox but I am getting these errors during the build:

```
ERROR in ./~/normalize.css/normalize.css
Module parse failed: /home/jules/projects/tourbnb-frontend/node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css Line 9: Unexpected token {
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|  */
| 
| html {
|   font-family: sans-serif; /* 1 */
|   -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
 @ ./src/index.js 29:0-24

ERROR in ./~/react-toolbox/lib/app/App.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./style in /home/jules/projects/tourbnb-frontend/node_modules/react-toolbox/lib/app
 @ ./~/react-toolbox/lib/app/App.js 11:13-31
```

This is my index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import ToolboxApp from 'react-toolbox/lib/app';
import App from './containers/App';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import './styles/styles.scss'; //Yep, that's right. You can import SASS/CSS files too! Webpack will run the associated loader and plug this into the page.
import 'normalize.css';

const store = configureStore();

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ToolboxApp>
      <App />
    </ToolboxApp>
  </Provider>, document.getElementById('app')
);
```

And this is my webpack.config.js
    // For info about this file refer to webpack and webpack-hot-middleware documentation
    // Rather than having hard coded webpack.config.js for each environment, this
    // file generates a webpack config for the environment passed to the getConfig method.
    import webpack from 'webpack';
    import path from 'path';
    import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin';

```
const developmentEnvironment = 'development' ;
const productionEnvironment = 'production';
const testEnvironment = 'test';

const getPlugins = function (env) {
  const GLOBALS = {
    'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(env),
    __DEV__: env === developmentEnvironment
  };

  const plugins = [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(GLOBALS) //Tells React to build in prod mode. https://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.html
  ];

  switch (env) {
    case productionEnvironment:
      plugins.push(new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css'));
      plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin());
      plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin());
      break;

    case developmentEnvironment:
      plugins.push(new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin());
      plugins.push(new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin());
      break;
  }

  return plugins;
};

const getEntry = function (env) {
  const entry = [];

  if (env === developmentEnvironment ) { // only want hot reloading when in dev.
    entry.push('webpack-hot-middleware/client');
  }

  entry.push('./src/index');

  return entry;
};

const getLoaders = function (env) {
  const loaders = [{ test: /\.js$/, include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'), loaders: ['babel', 'eslint'] }];

  if (env === productionEnvironment ) {
    // generate separate physical stylesheet for production build using ExtractTextPlugin. This provides separate caching and avoids a flash of unstyled content on load.
    loaders.push({
      test: /(\.css|\.scss)$/,
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("css?sourceMap!sass?sourceMap")
    });
  } else {
    loaders.push({
      test: /(\.css|\.scss)$/,
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap', 'sass?sourceMap']
    });
  }

  return loaders;
};

function getConfig(env) {
  return {
    debug: true,
    devtool: env === productionEnvironment  ? 'source-map' : 'cheap-module-eval-source-map', // more info:https://webpack.github.io/docs/build-performance.html#sourcemaps and https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool
    noInfo: true, // set to false to see a list of every file being bundled.
    entry: getEntry(env),
    target: env === testEnvironment ? 'node' : 'web', // necessary per https://webpack.github.io/docs/testing.html#compile-and-test
    output: {
      path: __dirname + '/dist', // Note: Physical files are only output by the production build task `npm run build`.
      publicPath: '',
      filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: getPlugins(env),
    module: {
      loaders: getLoaders(env)
    }
  };
}

export default getConfig;
```

What might be the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that include in loaders excluded node_modules. I just omitted the include and it was fine:

```
loaders.push({
  test: /(\.css|\.scss)$/,
  loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap', 'sass?sourceMap']
});
```

Comment: I see `exclude: /node_modules/` in most configs on the web. What’s the

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, maybe you have to add `.css` to your resolved extensions in the webpack config. Something like this maybe:
`resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.css']
  }`

See [this page in the webpack docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-extensions) for more info.

Comment: "Hmm, maybe you have to add .css to your resolved extensions in the webpack config." - this sounds more like a question than an answer, and may be better formatted as a comment.

Comment: Isn't that just semantics? Would it had been better if I had said "My best guess is..." or "I think that you..."? Or are you only supposed to answer if you are totally super certain in your answer (I'm asking earnestly, new to to all this)?

Comment: you don't need to be 100% certain AFAIK, but maybe make it sound less uncertain by changing the "hmmm. Maybe you have to add..." To something else.